# Symfony validation using multi dimensional collection

Tags: php, symfony, validation, multidimensional-array

I am trying a sample validation using symfony validator, my data array looks like:

```
$data = array("firstname" => "", "lastname" => "", "address" => array("street" => "", "city" => ""));
```

My constraints array is like

```
 $valueConstraints = array("firstname" => new NotBlank(array('message' => "Please fill firstname")),
            "lastname" => new NotBlank(array('message' => "Please fill lastname")),
            "address" => array("street" => new NotBlank(array('message' => "Please fill the street for address field")),
                "city" => new NotBlank(array('message' => "Please fill city for  address field"))));
```

But when I am trying to build a collection

```
$collectionConstraint = new Collection($constraints)
```

It throws an constraint error:

```
The options \"street\", \"city\" do not exist in constraint
```

**street** and **city** options are coming under the address category, don't know whether constraints can be created in a multi dimensional array  format using symfony validator.

Comment: it should be `new ArrayCollection($constraints);` see [docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but constraints does not have a class called ArrayCollection

Comment: why dont you simply add single `NotBlank` constraint. why separate for each value. add notblank on property/field instead value.

Comment: Thats not a problem,  its just a sample.But the multidimensional is the main issue.